# Why I cannot pass the data from Controller to the img tag in View

Tags: java, html, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC project. I tried to pass String variable from Controller to the img tag in the View. This String variable contains a URL. In the .html file, I tried different ways to write the img tags, but none of them works. I did not see any pictures displayed on the web page. I do not know why the value of the String variable was not pass to this image variable. All of my URLs are stored in MongoDB in the format of String. Who can tell me how to correctly pass these String values to the img tag in .html file

```
<img src= "${image}">
<img src= ${image}>
<img src= "${image}"/>
```

I want to see the pictures displayed.

Comment: something like that: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ add model attribute `model.addAttribute("image", "https://imgru.com/abc1234");` and return a name of the view that is processed by one of available template engines (in the example from link it is Thymeleaf)

Comment: the template then should be something like: `<img th:src="@{${image}}"/>`, probably not the best way to express, but works, Thymeleaf is more focused on relative links: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-more-than-one-value-at-a-time

Comment: @VladimirL. Hello, I have done the exact the same thing. @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getOneShoe(Model model) {
        List<Shoe> lists = repository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("image",lists.get(0).url);
        return "greeting.html";
    } Can you come up with more solutions?

Comment: @VladimirL.Thank you for your help! My problem has been solved.

Comment: usually it should be `return "greeting";` (without `.html`) and you **must** configure the template engine, e.g. include `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` if you are using Spring Boot, or initialize `org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine` bean for classical war-application, see: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect

Comment: @VladimirL. Can I consult you another question. I want to pass a list of java objects to the template, there are more than 100 objects in this list, and each object has three String properties. Can you tell me how to write html code to loop through the list and display each java object?

Comment: :) I'm not so good at using Thymeleaf (just used couple times in pet-projects), but they have an operator `th:each`, see this example: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach